# (Android) detect when another app is launched / launch count of all app

Tags: android

I would like to get the information about another app last time used , or launch time ,or launch count of another app. (Just like the information of usage statistics)

[Usage statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIkNb.png)
[information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIkNb.png)

I have found some similar question and answer at here.
But those doesn't work in android M or android L.

Is there some method can get the information what i need?(example If can)

Thanks.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIkNb.png):[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIkNb.png): [image]

Comment: You will need to use UsageStatsManager on Android 5.0.1+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the `UsesStats` of the top foreground Applications. but using this the user have rights to **Accept** or **Decline** for each app separately.
getting the permission

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
```

and this will return the foreground applications..

```
    String topPackageName ;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService("usagestats");                       
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    // We get usage stats for the last 10 seconds
    List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000*10, time);                                    
    // Sort the stats by the last time used
    if(stats != null) {
        SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long,UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),usageStats);
        }                    
        if(!mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
            topPackageName =  mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();                                   
        }                                       
    }
}
```

Comment: getRecentTasks only returns your application on Android 5.0.1+. See https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses